# Xamarin Forms How to add commas to an entry field that will continually be updated with data (integers)

Tags: forms, xamarin, formatting, label

I am building a mobile application with Xamarin Forms for (IOS & Android) I have created an entry field that is bound to a data source to retrieve quantities. I need to format that data within the view and allow it to be editable and always display commas if there is a number present and commas are required, e.g. (9,000 vs 9,000,000 etc). Currently the behavior allows the commas to only display when the data is initially retrieved (called) when starting the application, using the ("{Binding example.Mydata, StringFormat='{0:n0}'}"). I have tried many variations {0:n} , {F:0} , {0:n0} etc.

I have tried many variations {0:n} , {F:0} , {0:n0} etc. The behavior continues to be the same. The initial return will display the value with the commas but once edited the commas will not reappear.

I have also tried creating a behavior class

```
{
    public class FieldFormatValidator : Behavior<Entry>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.PropertyChanged += Bindable_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.PropertyChanged += Bindable_PropertyChanged;
    }
    void Bindable_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs 
      e)
    {
        var entry = sender as Entry;
        double doubleValue = 0;
        if (entry != null)
        {
            try
            {
            //object s = null;
            doubleValue = 
        Double.ParseDouble(entry.ToString().Replace(',', '.'));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException)
        {
            //Error
            }
        }
    }

Xaml:

 <Entry Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
     WidthRequest="150" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Done" Text=" 
     {Binding 
     Opportunity.MyExample}"                              
     AutomationId="OppAnnualQtyValueEntry">
         <Entry.Behaviors>
             <local:FieldFormatValidator/>
             </Entry.Behaviors>
         </Entry>
  </Grid>
```

Please help with inline Xaml code for allowing an entry field to be editable and maintain comma format or help with creating a behavior class that can also place the commas into the entry field. Thank you

Comment: https://xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Behavior`. And I have created a simple demo to achieve this function, the main code is as follows:

class `NumberMaskBehavior`

```
   public class NumberMaskBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        ///
        /// Attaches when the page is first created.
        /// 

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
        {
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
        }

        ///
        /// Detaches when the page is destroyed.
        /// 

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
        {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
        }

        private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** args.NewTextValue *** " + args.NewTextValue + "  -----  args.OldTextValue =  " + args.OldTextValue);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue))
            {
                // If the new value is longer than the old value, the user is
                //if (args.OldTextValue != null && args.NewTextValue.Length < args.OldTextValue.Length)
                //    return;

                var value = args.NewTextValue;

                string actual_number = "";
                actual_number = value;
                actual_number = actual_number.Replace(",", "");

                string result_last = dataFormat(actual_number);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("****   result = " + result_last);


               int actual_length = actual_number.Length;

                ((Entry)sender).Text = result_last;
            }
        }

        public static String dataFormat(String text)
        {
            DecimalFormat df = null;
            if (text.IndexOf(".") > 0)
            {//include decimal
                if (text.Length - text.IndexOf(".") - 1 == 0)
                {//include a decimal
                    df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.");
                }
                else if (text.Length - text.IndexOf(".") - 1 == 1)
                {//include two decimals
                    df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.0");
                }
                else
                {//include more than two decimal
                    df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                }
            }
            else
            {//only integer
                df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0");
            }
            double number = 0.0;
            try
            {
                number = Double.Parse(text);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                number = 0.0;
            }
            return df.Format(number);

        }
    }
```

And use like this:

```
  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill"
             VerticalOptions="Fill"
             Padding="5,20,5,5">
    <Label Text=" Number Formatting"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           FontSize="Medium"></Label>
    <Entry  Keyboard="Numeric" >
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <behavior:NumberMaskBehavior  />              
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

The effect is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you I will attempt to implement your recommendation

Comment: The code above will build only for Android. It requires adding the Mono.Android.dll, Which causes the deployment to the IOS simulator to fail? Please help with that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just modified dataFormat function to work on both ios and android

```
 public static String dataFormat(String text)
        {
            string format = null;
            if (text.IndexOf(".") > 0)
            {//include decimal
                if (text.Length - text.IndexOf(".") - 1 == 0)
                {//include a decimal
                    format = "###,##0.";
                }
                else if (text.Length - text.IndexOf(".") - 1 == 1)
                {//include two decimals
                    format = "###,##0.0";
                }
                else
                {//include more than two decimal
                    format = "###,##0.00";
                }
            }
            else
            {//only integer
                format = "###,##0";
            }
            double number = 0.0;
            try
            {
                number = Double.Parse(text);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                number = 0.0;
            }


            return number.ToString(format);

        }
```