# How to display a comma value on label - xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have:

```
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:F0} $'}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="#2bff00" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

But my property from the object is:

```
JsonProperty("price_usd")]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

So the real value is: `"price_usd":"3824.56"` and my label display 3824 without comma ?

Comment: Take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514107/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-commas-to-an-entry-field-that-will-continually-be-updat

Comment: I want to change this one: StringFormat='{0:F0} to get a comma ? If it's possible. I not want to edit c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) in the documentation. Also, here are some quick examples:

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);         // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
```

You can use these formats inside your `.xaml`.