# Add thousands separator to entry integer value as user types

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an app using Xamarin Forms and it is meant to perform a few calculations using the values that the user types. Some of the values are large numbers, like milions or bilions, and I need to show the thousands separator as the user types, so they won't have to count the zeroes on the entries. Also, these are integer values and CAN'T show the decimal places.

For example, when the user types `9000`, the entry should show `9.000`. Then, when they add another 0, the thousands separator should be relocated to show `90.000` and so on.

FYI: the app culture is set to pt-BR, so the thousands separator is a dot and the decimals separator is a comma.

I tried to simply set the text binding of the entry as `<Entry Text="{Binding MyObj.MyIntNumber, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:N0}'}"/>` but it only adds the first separator and only considerates the first 4 digits.

I found this [currency converter](https://github.com/TBertuzzi/Xamarin.Forms.ConvertersPack/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.ConvertersPack/Converters/CurrencyConverter.cs) which does the thousands formatting as I needed, so I tried to change the `.ToString("C")` to `.ToString("N0")` and set the text binding of the entry as `<Entry Text="{Binding MyObj.MyIntNumber, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ThousandsConverter}}"/>`,  but it didn't work and the text typed is not shown in the entry.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: there are many existing questions that are similar, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514107/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-commas-to-an-entry-field-that-will-continually-be-updat

Comment: @Jason I found similar questions, including this one you linked, but they don't work the way I need... what should I change on the answer to correspond it to my culture info format? (. as thousands separator)

Comment: I would imagine you need to swap "," and "." in their proposed solution

Comment: If you still can't get it working after the above advice, then **add to question as text** all relevant code: the xaml of your entry field, any code behind that uses/affects that entry, and the converter. Then say **exactly** what happens when you type - nothing shows or only the numbers show? Also, start **debugging**: put a breakpoint in `Convert` method - does it get called as each character is typed? What is `value`?

Comment: Tried many times and in many different ways, but in my best result I typed `1234567`, which got correctly formatted as `1,234,567` in the entry, but the binding value is `1234`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to undelete the question, because after MANY hours and tests, I managed to alter the [currency converter](https://github.com/TBertuzzi/Xamarin.Forms.ConvertersPack/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.ConvertersPack/Converters/CurrencyConverter.cs) code that I found to format my integer values the way I wanted. Here's my solution:

```cs
public class ThousandsSeparatorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = culture.NumberFormat;
        var temp = Int32.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("N0");
        return temp;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string valueFromString = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", "");

        if (valueFromString.Length <= 0)
            return 0L;

        long valueLong;
        if (!long.TryParse(valueFromString, out valueLong))
            return 0L;

        if (valueLong <= 0)
            return 0L;

        return valueLong;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.